# Implementing a linked list using Queues: Python

Tags: python, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue using linked lists. It mostly works however I think there is a problem at my `is_empty` function, because when I run the code and try to dequeue when there's nothing in the queue, it should say `IndexError("Can't dequeue from empty queue.")` but my tests tell me it returned nothing

The test:

```
Failed example:
    result = q.dequeue()
Expected:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    IndexError: Can't dequeue from empty queue.
Got nothing
```

The code for dequeue and is_empty functions:

```
def dequeue(self):
               
        if self.is_empty(): 
            return IndexError("Can't dequeue from empty queue.")
        else:
            to_return = self.head.item
            self.head = self.head.next_node
            return to_return
        

    def is_empty(self):
        """ returns True if the queue is empty """
        return self.head is None
```

Comment: can you post the rest of the class' code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting to throw the error, use the ***raise*** statement instead of **return**

Here is sample code:

```
class Queue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.is_empty(): 
            raise IndexError("Can't dequeue from empty queue.")
        else:
            to_return = self.head.item
            self.head = self.head.next_node
            return to_return
        
    def is_empty(self):
        """ returns True if the queue is empty """
        return self.head is None

queue = Queue()

item = queue.dequeue()

print(item)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    item = queue.dequeue()
  File "test2.py", line 8, in dequeue
    raise IndexError("Can't dequeue from empty queue.")
IndexError: Can't dequeue from empty queue.
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it was raise I just didn't realise I had written return instead of raise. thank you!